# Using articles in a prompt

Tags: articles

There is a prompt in a program

What is the correct form of it?

Enter height of a triangle

Enter a height of a triangle

Enter the height of a triangle

Enter the height of the triangle

Comment: Add more background to your query, s'il vous plaît.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Enter the height of the triangle'.  Since it is a computer program, we are indeed specific about the specific triangle - so it is 'the' everywhere.

Comment: Sounds too verbose

Answer (score 3):

*"Enter triangle height"*.

Since it is a computer program, we are not keen to be offensively over-verbose.